# Align text in \hfill environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I arrange the text lines in the \hfill ? Is using a tabular environment the only way around this ?

```
\documentclass{letter} % Uses 10pt
\usepackage{marvosym} % add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\large\bf First Last}
\end{flushleft}
\medskip\hrule height 1pt
%%%%%%%%%%% how can I left align the different lines in this flushright ? %%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushright}
\hfill Address, Apt XXX\\
\hfill City, ST ZIP-XXXX\\
\hfill {\Large\Telefon} (XXX)-XXX-XXXX
\end{flushright} 

%%%%%%%%%%% how can I left align the different lines in this flushright ? %%%%%%%%%%%

\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a `tabular` environment?

Comment: don't use `{}` in `{\large\bf First Last}` the `flushleft` already scopes the size change, and the `{}` just makes the text use the wrong baseline if it wraps to a new line, and `\bfseries` is preferable to `\bf` which is just for compatibility with LaTeX 2.09. The `hfill` in the flushright aren ot doing anything as the text is already flush right?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `tabular` with `l@{}` (fully left) alignment, for example.

```
\documentclass{letter} % Uses 10pt
\usepackage{marvosym} % add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\large\bf First Last}
\end{flushleft}
\medskip\hrule height 1pt
%%%%%%%%%%% how can I left align the different lines in this flushright ? %%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}  %% as observed by Werner, use l@{} instead of l
 Address, Apt XXX\\
 City, ST ZIP-XXXX\\
 {\Large\Telefon} (XXX)-XXX-XXXX
\end{tabular}\end{flushright} 

%%%%%%%%%%% how can I left align the different lines in this flushright ? %%%%%%%%%%%

\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you want to push them to the right just use `flushright`

```
\begin{flushright}
 Address, Apt XXX\\
 City, ST ZIP-XXXX\\
 {\Large\Telefon} (XXX)-XXX-XXXX
\end{flushright}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the contents in a left-aligned `\Longstack`.

```
\documentclass{letter} % Uses 10pt
\usepackage{marvosym} % add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\large\bf First Last}
\end{flushleft}
\medskip\hrule height 1pt
%%%%%%%%%%% how can I left align the different lines in this flushright ? %%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushright}
\hfill 
\Longstack[l]{Address, Apt XXX\\
City, ST ZIP-XXXX\\
{\Large\Telefon} (XXX)-XXX-XXXX}
\end{flushright} 

%%%%%%%%%%% how can I left align the different lines in this flushright ? %%%%%%%%%%%

\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page
\end{document}
```

[image]